# Iterate through object literal and replace strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Can someone help me with the syntax for how to loop through an object literal using jQuery `$.each` and replace strings that match in each item?

If I have:

```
var foo = {
    item1: "Mary had a little lamb",
    item2: "Whose fleece was white as snow",
    item3: "Johnny ha a little lamb",
    item4: "What's the deal with lambs?"
}
```

And I want to replace the word `lamb` with `lion`, where inside the $.each function do I replace the item?

I've tried:

```
$.each(foo, function(key, value){
     return value.replace(/lamb/, "lion");
}
```

But it doesn't replace the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to replace the text & update the value of the object

```js
var foo = {
  item1: "Mary had a little lamb",
  item2: "Whose fleece was white as snow",
  item3: "Johnny has a little lamb",
  item4: "What's the deal with lambs?"
}
$.each(foo, function(i) {
  foo[i] = foo[i].replace('lamb', 'lion')
});
console.log(foo)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't realize you could iterate the function using $.each and just the object key (without explicitly noting the value in the function).