# Match and replace all strings inside object with strings from another object

Tags: javascript, string

I have an object which contains UTF-8 characters as strings - I figured I could make another object with the list of characters and how I'd like to replace them?

## The Data Object

```
var data = [
  {"my_string":"ABC &#038; I","value":13,"key":8},
  {"my_string":"A &#8220;B&#8221; C","value":12,"key":9}
 ];
```

## The Replacement Object

```
var str_to_change = [
    {value: "&#038;", replace: "&"},
    {value: "&#8220;", replace: ""},
    {value: "&#8221;", replace: ""}
];
```

I'd like to write a function where anytime a `str_to_change.value` is seen inside `data.my_string`, replace it with `str_to_change.replace`

Is this the best way to go about changing various character strings, and how would I execute this? I found this: [Iterate through object literal and replace strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472159/iterate-through-object-literal-and-replace-strings) but it's a little more complex since I'm not just replacing with a singular string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than an array of objects, consider constructing just a *single* object with multiple keys:

```
const replacements = {
  "&#038;": "&",
  "&#8220;": '',
  "&#8221;": '',
};
```

Then, with the keys, [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493) characters with a special meaning in regular expressions, join the keys by `|`, construct a regular expression, and have a replacer function access the matched substring as a property of the `replacements` object:

```js
var str_to_change = [{value: "&#038;", replace: "&"},
{value: "&#8220;", replace: ""},
{value: "&#8221;", replace: ""}];
const replacements = Object.fromEntries(str_to_change.map(({ value, replace }) => [value, replace]));
const escape = s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
const pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).map(escape).join('|'), 'gi');

var data = [{
  "my_string": "ABC &#038; I",
  "value": 13,
  "key": 8
},
{
  "my_string": "A &#8220;B&#8221; C",
  "value": 12,
  "key": 9
}];

const mappedData = data.map(({ my_string, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  my_string: my_string.replace(
    pattern,
    prop => replacements[prop]
  )
}));
console.log(mappedData);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I love the idea of just matching the key value pairs for the strings I want to replace, this is great!